# Cassandra - check TTL on rows for table with 2 primary keys

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have the following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers_by_store(
   customer_token uuid,
   store_id uuid,
   customer_name,
   customer_address
   nickname text,
   created timestamp,
   PRIMARY KEY((customer_token, store_id)));
```

I set a TTL on the rows when I insert them, but how can I be sure that it set the TTL?

I tried the following queries but I just get errors.

```
SELECT TTL(customer_token, store_id) from customers_by_store;

SELECT TTL(customer_token) from customers_by_store;
```

Example of an error - `SyntaxException: line 1:32 mismatched input ',' expecting ')' (SELECT TTL (customer_token[,]...)`

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TTL()` function is similar to the `WRITETIME()` function, where it only operates on "payload" columns.  So it won't work on key columns.

```
SELECT TTL(customer_name) from customers_by_store;
```

Querying the TTL for `customer_name` or another non-key column works.